# Confused about details of oauth2 authorization and authentication after reading Django-salesforce documentation

Tags: python, django, oauth-2.0, salesforce

I am trying to integrate Salesforce with a Django application, so users can login into my site and push data themselves into the salesforce database. I have read the [django-salesforce](https://github.com/django-salesforce/django-salesforce/tree/main) github page, and I confirmed that I can make postman calls to the database with oauth2 tokens, but I have some questions which probably stems from my ignorance of this subject.

1. If I hardcode my username and password-concat-token into the django salesforce database settings, then won't all new database entries be authorized under my account? Ideally, shouldn't users authenticate into my application with their salesforce account, and then make API calls under the authorization of their own account? Or does this not matter at all?
2. Also, if I hardcode my username and password-concat-token like above, then do I need a separate authentication and authorization system? If I hardcode my token into the django database information like that, then theoretically any backend call would inject my account's oauth2 information to make API calls. I was hoping users could click on a "Sign in with Salesforce" button and be authenticated on my site that way, going 100% for the social login system and not make my own.

Any clarifications on my misunderstandings would be greatly appreciated!

I confirmed that I can make oauth2 authenticated postman calls, which is fine for developmental testing, but I am not sure how django-salesforce will authenticate their users with the "Login" with salesforce option. I tried searching through the readme and online documentation and I was still quite confused.